# Yolo object detection metrics

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, yolo

I have made some predictions and saved the results to YOLO format. Then I made a program to calculate metrics, every metric looks fine except Precision/Confidence curve. I guess the flatline at the start is because the prediction was made with confidence >= 0.3, but the weird downward spike on the right is ok? or it has to be some bug? [image]